# How can i use return app to not block this code

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to add a startup code to the  project

This is a code that works perfectly

```
    #include "App.h"
   #include "base/kernel/Entry.h"
    #include "base/kernel/Process.h"


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    using namespace xmrig;

    Process process(argc, argv);
    const Entry::Id entry = Entry::get(process);
    if (entry) {
        return Entry::exec(process, entry);
    }

    App app(&process);

    return app.exec();
}
```

but when i try add startup code like this

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
using namespace xmrig;
Process process(argc, argv);
const Entry::Id entry = Entry::get(process);
if (entry) {
    return Entry::exec(process, entry);


    int main(void)
    {
        TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];

        GetModuleFileName(NULL, szPath, MAX_PATH);

        HKEY newValue;

        RegOpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", &newValue);

        RegSetValueEx(newValue, "xmrig", 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)szPath, sizeof(szPath));

        RegCloseKey(newValue);
        return 0;

    }

    App app(&process);

    return app.exec();
```

I get an error E0020    identifier "app" is undefined

I'm totally new to cpp
And I do not understand why this does not work?

when I edit

```
App app(&process);
return app.exec();
```

to

```
App app(&process);
return 0();
```

I can build a project and startup works but console just open and closes immediately.

Comment: Is that a main function defined *inside* another main function? Are you sure you copied the code correctly?

Comment: Why do you have executable code outside of the `main` function?

Comment: You can't have multiple  `main()` functions in the same application. Also you can't define functions inside of other functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    using namespace xmrig;

    Process process(argc, argv);
    const Entry::Id entry = Entry::get(process);
    if (entry) {
        return Entry::exec(process, entry);
    }

    TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];
    DWORD dwLength = GetModuleFileName(NULL, szPath, MAX_PATH);

    HKEY hKey;
    if (RegOpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, TEXT("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run"), &hKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        RegSetValueEx(hKey, TEXT("xmrig"), 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)szPath, (dwLength+1) * sizeof(TCHAR));
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
    }

    App app(&process);
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Checking the return values of all registry function calls will help too

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the only registry function I don't check is `RegSetValueEx()`, because the particular value that is being written  simply tells Windows to run the calling app at OS startup, and should have no effect on whether `app.exec()` succeeds or fails.